# Best way to deploy multiple instances of same DB on MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

The issue:
I am in process of developing an SaaS solution. Part of this solution are two schemas: Interface and Production. The interface provides staging tables, from which the data is loaded into production. The problem is, that mainly i am an MS SQL developer, which means i am used to Database and Schema being separate levels.

The loading is done by stored procedures, referencing both schemas.

Now, the issue i am facing (luckily still fairle early in the dev. process) is that it is not possible to easily deploy several independent databases with both schemas on MySQL the same way it would be possible to do in MS SQL.

I am now facing three possibilities:

1. Merge the interface and production schema into one, using table prefixes
2. Use installation that uses the database name to replace macros in SQL scripts and creates schemas ie. Production_SITE050 and Interface_SITE050 in both structure and code.... however i dont like this very much
3. Use several parallel instances of MySQL (possible in theory but i don't see this as an acceptable way to go)

So the question is / are:

1. Which of the proposed solution is the way to go in your opinion
   and why?
2. Is there a way to implement the Database/Schema levels
   from MS SQL?
3. Did i miss another possibility

Thanks a lot for any constructive answers / debate
Have a nice day

Comment: Too late to use PostgreSQL? It has multiple databases with schemas

Comment: It sems i will have to take a look into that, but well, learning a third DB shouldnt be a problem.... i just hope that PostgreSQL isnt to MySQL what Oracle is to MS SQL :-/